# Changing the password of a java keystore programmatically

Tags: java, passwords, keystore, jks

How do I go about changing the password of a JKS keystore(and all entries in it) from java code?

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can rewrite keystore to the same file but different password with [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20char%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps expect4j is the answer. http://code.google.com/p/expect4j/

It ports original [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) package to java and it interacts well with prompts and stuff